# ti.applepay vs ti.paypal which is better?

Tags: paypal, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules, applepay

I want use the titanium module for payments.

I was unable to identify which one is better from below modules

1. ti.applepay
2. ti.paypal

What are the features of ti.applepay module?

what are the features of ti.paypal module?

Can any one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, they are there for different purposes.

**Ti.ApplePay** is for supporting payments with Apple Pay, using credit-cards linked to your Apple ID or custom ones you add to your iOS Wallet.

**Ti.PayPal** is for supporting payments with PayPal, using credit-cards or bank debit linked to your PayPal account.

So you could rather support both of them instead of just one, it's highly depending on your desired use-case. Hope that helps!